# PHP is unable to see env var when runing in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I have this docker-compose config.

The "app" is a PHP application. As you can see, 3 env vars are passed to the container.
However, after docker-compose up, PHP doesn't see these. They are not returned by getenv() and they cannot be found $_ENV either.

What's wrong here?

```
version: '3.4'
services: 
        db:
            image: postgres:11.0
            restart: always
            environment:
                POSTGRES_PASSWORD: testuser
                POSTGRES_USER: test
                POSTGRES_DB: db
            volumes: 
                - /data/db
        redis:
            image: redis:latest
            restart: always
            volumes: 
                - /data/redis
        app: 
            build:
                context: .
                dockerfile: Dockerfile
            environment: 
                - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://db:5432/db
                - REDIS_URL=tcp://redis:6379?database=1
                - NODE_ENV=development
            ports: 
                - '80:80'
            volumes: 
                - '${BASEDIR}:/var/www/some'
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

FROM ubuntu:18.04

```
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    software-properties-common \
    apt-utils \
    tzdata \
    locales

RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
RUN apt-get update

RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8

RUN echo "Europe/Budapest" > /etc/timezone && dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install \
        libglu1-mesa \
        less \
        vim \
        nginx \
        php7.4 \
        php7.4-fpm \
        php7.4-cli \
        php7.4-common \
        php7.4-curl \
        php-deepcopy \
        php7.4-gd \
        php7.4-mbstring \
        php7.4-pgsql \
        php7.4-soap \
        php7.4-xdebug \
        php7.4-zip \
        php7.4-xml \
        phpunit \
        npm && npm i -g npm

ENV NGINX_RUN_USER www-data
ENV NGINX_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV NGINX_LOG_DIR /var/log/nginx
ENV NGINX_LOCK_DIR /var/lock/nginx
ENV NGINX_PID_FILE /run/nginx.pid

RUN mkdir www
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/dbv.local/html
RUN chmod -R 755 /var/www/dbv.local

COPY ./php.ini /etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini
COPY ./dbv.local /etc/nginx/sites-available/dbv.local
COPY ./lib/aspose_php.so /usr/lib/php/20190902
COPY ./lib/libaspose_cpp_clang3_libstdcpp.so /usr/lib/libaspose_cpp_clang3_libstdcpp.so
COPY ./lib/libAspose.Slides_clang3_libstdcpp.so /usr/lib/libAspose.Slides_clang3_libstdcpp.so
COPY ./lib/libphpcpp.so.2.2 /usr/lib/libphpcpp.so.2.2

RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

RUN ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/dbv.local /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

ADD ./xdebug.ini /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/xdebug.ini
ADD ./aspose_php.ini /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/aspose_php.ini
ADD ./start.sh /root/start.sh

RUN ln -s /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/xdebug.ini /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/20-xdebug.ini
RUN ln -s /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/aspose_php.ini /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/aspose_php.ini
RUN ln -s /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/aspose_php.ini /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/aspose_php.ini

RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt-get clean

CMD ["/root/start.sh"]

EXPOSE 80 9000 5432
```

Edit:

start.sh is just a one liner

```
service php7.4-fpm start && nginx
```

Ubuntu 18 is necessary. I could use an official Nginx image though. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: What error are you getting, configuration looks alright, share the dockerfile too.

Comment: I'm not getting any error. PHP simply cannot see these env vars. Accroding the phpinfo() only 2 env vars are defined: HOME and another one. Please see the Dockerfile above

Comment: Can you also post the contents of `start.sh` or an approximation?

Comment: I believe I've had this issue before, but I can't be sure it's the same because I'm using one of the official PHP images.  In my case I see that I've currently configured `variables_order=ECPCS` as a cmd line option, but presumably you could do it in php.ini.  I don't know your reasoning for building from Ubuntu 18, nor for using the same container for nginx, but I would recommend using discreet containers for discreet services if possible.  I say this realizing full well that it is not always possible.  If you post `start.sh` I'd be happy to take a look and see if anything else jumps out.

Comment: Tried variables_order=ECPCS, didn't help

Comment: Should I use official nginx and php images instead?

Comment: All the environments can't be access? or only those with : inside ... ?  try to put the DATABASE_URL and REDIS_URL in double quotes. i.e DATABASE_URL="postgresql://db:5432/db".